# DE attribute not recognizable in exclusion script

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, journeybuilder

i am trying to remove contacts of DE from receiving email which has a value in column named 'AffPersonPGUID' matching to the values present in a column by same name in DE named DE_ContactID using the below exclusion script

ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE_ContactID_Suppression", "AffPersonPGUID", AffPersonPGUID))> 0

the journey is not activating in which i have used this exclusion script in one of the emails, error being that AffPersonPGUID is an undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `AffPersonPGUID` exists as a field in your Event Source Data Extension? Please try the following:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE_ContactID_Suppression", "AffPersonPGUID", AttributeValue("AffPersonPGUID")))> 0
```

Comment: Hi @eliot 
thanks alot for the update, things worked. Just one more query can we use two exclusion using some or condition like 

ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE_ContactID_Suppression", "AffPersonPGUID", AttributeValue("AffPersonPGUID")))> 0 or RowCount(LookupRows("Global_and_Multi-Group","EmailAddress", emailaddr))>0

can we use it this way or some other thing needs to be done. Please Help

Comment: I've never tried using an OR statement with two `rowcount` functions in an Exclusion Script, but I can't see why it would not work. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes i tried yesterday, things seems to be fine. doing second checks